# C string array not correct output

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, output

The last thing shouldn't be there, it should show only the numbers,can someone tell me why this happens? When I put for example char [5] = "12345"; it works just fine and remove the if in the fors

```
   for (k = 0; k < 12; k++)
{
        c[k] = 'g';
        printf("%", c[k]);
}
printf("input:");
scanf("%s", c);
int j, i;

    unsigned int pat;
    for (j = 0; j <5; j++) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            if (c[i+1]!='g')
            {

                pat = get_row_pattern(c[i], j);
                print_bits(pat, NUM_COLS + 1);

            }


        }
        print_char('\n');
    }
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: no, its not but the other part is given code for assignment and that's why I haven't added it here

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example with 123, `scanf` will overwrite the first 4 elements of the `c` array with the characters `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, and a zero. You may want to change your program logic to not print anything if the array element is `'\0'`.

Comment: Yes I changed c[k] in the first for to be equal to '\0' and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot